# How to render this Joomla module to another position without loosing its connection to the article

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

This is code from the Dizi-images module (plugin/content/images/images.php) for Joomla. This works, it publishes a image or image gallery at the end of a specific article.

But if I want to publish the image/image gallery to another position (by changing its position in Joomla admin and the getModules-value in the code below) it looses its "connection" to the article. It shows up on every article on the site.

Is it possible to make this code below to be able to publish the image/image gallery to another position without loosing its connection to the specific article?

```
/*
 * load front end images module
 */

public function onContentAfterDisplay( $context, &$row, &$params, $limitstart = null )
{
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $option = $jinput->get('option', '', '');
    $view = $jinput->get('view', '', '');

    if( $context == 'com_content.article' && ( $modules = JModuleHelper::getModules( 'images' ) ) )
    {
        return JModuleHelper::renderModule( $modules[ 0 ] );
    }

    return '';
}
```

Thanks

Magnus

[image: Screenshot of the modules that I change position on]

Screenshot of the modules that I change position on (Joomla Admin/Extensions/Module Manager/)

The plug-in I use is "Dizi images gallery"-extension.

[image: The Dizi-tab in Article Manager. Where you add images to the article your in]

This shows the Dizi-images Tab. Where you add images/image gallery to the article your in.

Comment: Don't use use `JRequest` with Joomla 3.x as it's deprecated. You need to be using `JFactory::getApplication()->input->get()`

Comment: I updated the code to JInput. I´m not a programmer so please tell me if it´s not correct.

Answer (score 1):

These three lines of code will allow you load and render any existing modules as needed.

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_myimagemodulename', 'Images Gallery');
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module, array('style' => 'xhtml'));
```

If you want to manage from the back end, you will need to make a duplicate of the existing module with different menu position assignments.  It sounds like the only limitation is the source images folder, so the module should not mind!

** EDIT **

To create a new position like "right", you would need to add a new jdoc element to your templates index.php where you would like the new position:

```
<jdoc:include type="moduels" name="right" style="xhtml" />
```

Then in your templates manifest XML file, add the new position to list of existing positions:

```
<position>right</position>
```

Now if you navigate to the module copy you want to place there, you would be able to select the newly created "right" position.

** EDIT **

Noticed something in how the module instance is being loaded, the name should reflect the the module type *and* name.

```
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules( 'images', 'Images gallery' )
```

And definitely migrate away from JRequest.

Comment: I´ve tried this and some codes close to this. It seems it looses the connection to the article, which probably are ($context == 'com_content.article'). The module shows up on all pages. And how do I render it to a specific (for example "right") position?

Comment: Yeah that solution works for the positioning. Now the most important problem. Showing the images/image gallery only on the article they are added to (see new screenshot). This works in the original code but it puts it after the content (onContentAfterDisplay) and the code doing that is probably $context == 'com_content.article'. That code does not work when the module renders at a position. I have tried google for a solution but no luck. I probably haven´t the correct keywords. I don't know what keywords to use now. Sorry for the never ending story...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a new instance of the module for the other position? That way this module stays just as it is and the new module is published elsewhere without conflicting with the code you have.

Also agree with Lodder, use JInput.

Comment: It doesn´t create a new module for every image/image gallery. The plugin use the same module for all image/image galleries. So I only change the existing modules position in Joomla admins "Module Manager" (se picture above).

Comment: And a great idea about keeping the original code. If so the solution would probably need a if else statement so the image galleries doesn´t show up on both places.